# Can I do sizdah (Sajdah) without salat?

Tags: dua, sajda

Assalamualaykum,

Is it allowed to do sizdah (Sajdah) without salat? Is there any practice of it?

JazakAllah Khair.

Comment: oh, yeah. Actually I assume the mentions link could be profitable for the questioner to find his or her response.

Answer (score 3):

Walaikum Assalam,

Yes it is permissible to do sajdah (sizdah) without offering salah (prayer). It must be in the direction of qibla if known. Otherwise if direction of qibla is not known, your can perform it but keeping in mind that qibla is in upfront of you and God is up watching. And Allah knows the best.

Comment: ,Can I perform it without wudu too? at any state?

Comment: Yes, one can perform sajdah without wadu. But if possible, it's better to do wadu. However, if one requires Ablution then it is better to first remove any Nijasat from his body & get cleaned himself (i.e. taharat) then perform any ibadah.